# For Loop with dynamic numbers in timeout

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, for-loop, settimeout

I have a for loop that is running a timeout function that needs dynamic numbers but instead I'm getting the end result instead of the increments in some cases.

Here's my code (p.s. yes I realize setting 'start' variable inside for loop is not ideal):

```
var new_answer_start = 0;
var seconds = 0;
for (start=0; start<50; start++) {
    new_answer_start = new_answer_start + 50;
    seconds = seconds + 10000; //10 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){reloadXMLDoc(xmlurl, new_answer_start);},seconds);
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that increasing every 10 seconds the function will run with the new_answer_start equaling increments of 50.  Instead I'm getting every 10 seconds the function is outputting each time starting at 2500 (the last set of numbers after 50 loops).  I've had a similar issue before, something to do with closures and I used "let" to fix it then.  However when I tried:

```
let new_answer_start = new_answer_start + 50;
```

I started getting NaN (not a number) errors.  I thought it was weird that the timeout would increment in seconds (10, 20, 30, etc) but not the variable sent to the function.  I'm assuming that's because once the function goes to run 10 seconds later, the variable increment has completed to the end.  So how do I send the 'fixed' number to the function?

After doing research on similar questions here, I also tried putting the number into a closure:

```
setTimeout(function(){reloadXMLDoc(xmlurl, (new_answer_start));},seconds);
```

But this still start outputting at 2500.

Comment: Most developers would only run one settimeout and call the next iteration when the function reloadXMLDoc is called.

Comment: That's not a bad idea...something like at the end of the "reloadXMLDoc" function, a setTimeout function call back to itself? I could add a count inside the function and continue executing the setTimeout call back to the same function until the count reaches 50.  Would this create any 'issues/errors' calling the function back in on itself? If I avoided the obvious endless loop with a count function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an actual closure:

```
setTimeout((function (new_answer_start) {
    return function () {
        reloadXMLDoc(xmlurl, new_answer_start);
    };
})(new_answer_start), seconds);
```

Comment: I'm assuming at "reloadXMLDoc(xmlurl, new_answer_start;" you actually meant: "reloadXMLDoc(xmlurl, new_answer_start)"?

Comment: THANKS! After I fixed the "typo" this worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for.  Obviously, I need to understand closure's better...

Answer (score -1):

```
window.new_answer_start = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    window.new_answer_start = window.new_answer_start + 50;
}, 10000);
```

Comment: You should probably explain that.

Comment: I get how making it a global variable with the window prefix "might" work.  However this now creates an interval, which I really don't want.  I don't want to continue running my "reloadXMLDoc" function forever.  I just want to be able to run it ~20-50 times based on some other criteria and I need to pass the increasing "new_answer_start" variable to that function each time and it needs to be delayed from the main function.